# What does this JS snippet do? `"development" !== 'production'`

Tags: javascript, boolean

It's all over this [react.js file](https://github.com/reactjs/react-bower/blob/master/react.js#L836):

```
if ("development" !== 'production') {
  var typeofSpec = typeof spec;
  var isMixinValid = typeofSpec === 'object' && spec !== null;

  "development" !== 'production' ? warning(isMixinValid, '%s: You\'re attempting to include a mixin that is either null ' + 'or not an object. Check the mixins included by the component, ' + 'as well as any mixins they include themselves. ' + 'Expected object but got %s.', Constructor.displayName || 'ReactClass', spec === null ? null : typeofSpec) : void 0;
}
```

When would it ever be false? In what way is it useful? Was it autogenerated?

Comment: It looks to me like a trick to be used with "Find and Replace," so that the dev can easily switch to production mode by replacing all occurrences of `"development"` with `"production"`

Comment: Maybe a preprocessor? `"development" !== 'production'` must always be true.

Comment: @4castle it implies they don't know one can use variables for that.

Comment: @zerkms maybe the developers thought global variables were bad, hence they avoided that by _not_ having variables. ...but yeah, while a bit odd, I can see the strings being auto-replaced. Not sure why it wasn't a variable but still.

Comment: @vlaz it actually is the opposite - the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is substituted with the `'development'` string.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `"development" !== 'production'` is to enable development mode. The reason it is done this way is so that the block is removed from the production build during minification.

When building for production, `"production" !== "production"` can never be `true`, so the block is removed by the minifier.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your input. What build system works this way?

Comment: @DiegoSalazar I'm not sure I quite understand. The source is probably similar to `__Env__ !== 'production'` and then `__Env__` is replaced with the env string. Then (if production) that code is ran through a minifier and the minifier is able to detect dead code, and removes the block. Does this answer your question?